# Duplicate Characters in string

Tags: c++, string

`Empty` function returns to the function that whether the string is empty or not. I was doing similar thing in my program.

I was writing a program in which two similar characters needs to be eliminated.
 *This is my code:-*

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"enter a name";
    getline(cin,str);
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++)
    {
        int x=i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<str.size();j++)
        {
        if(str[x]==str[j])
        {

            str[x]='\0';
            str[j]='\0';

        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        }
    }
    if(str.empty())
    {
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<str;
    }

}
```

But when the string is empty, the output should show **EMPTY** on the screen.

This is not happening as the `if` loop is not running.

I think there might be one of the mistake:-

- Either the string contain null character so the `str.empty()` is not working
- Either there is problem with  `if`

**P.S. - Suggestion would be highly appreciated.**

Comment: What do you think `str[x]='\0';` does?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you set all characters in `std::string` to null terminator doesn't make it `empty()`. It still has the same length as it had before, just different content. `std::string` has built-in mechanism for handling length of the string, so it doesn't have to rely on special characters like C-style strings.

There are several ways out, the simplest would be to utilize the [*erase-remove idiom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) and remove all the null characters from string after loop:

```
#include <algorithm>

str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\0'), str.end());
//str now doesn't contain any \0 characters
```

This solution is best, because you can use `str` correctly then - it is truly a string with all similar characters removed.

---

You could also use functions for handling C-strings, which do stop at first null terminator, so instead of `str.empty()` you check

```
#include <cstring>

strlen(str.c_str()) == 0
//length of 0 means str has \0 at first place
```

The downside is that you don't know whether all of the characters are `\0`. You only check whether first one is null terminator.